# Inventor + Dynamo

Tags: c#, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I installed Dynamo Studio for myself and wrote in C # my dll-library, which I imported into the Dynamo project. Thus, I created my own custom-nodes for Dynamo, with which I can work through Dynamo with Inventor documents.

But in the process of testing this approach, I had serious difficulties with the failure of Dynamo to import my library after calling some standard methods on Inventor objects.

For examples, I had a problem when calling the Add() method for the PropertySet object. After calling it, the library is not imported into Dynamo. At the same time, there are no problems with the Delete() method.

https://autode.sk/2pGAEdX

I have a request to the community - please respond to those who have already tried to work with Inventor via Dynamo. Maybe you have already encountered similar problems and found solutions. I really need your experience.

Thank you!

Comment: An alternative solution was found. Its essence is depicted in the picture. If someone will solve the problem of pairing Inventor and Dynamo, then write to me, I will tell you more.

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/556306iFC3044EBC24F88FD/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999